# Upgrade spring 3.X to 5.X shows error while running application

Tags: java, spring, soap, apache-axis

I have updated the spring version from 3 to 5 but i see error when i make a request to my application

```
Spring context file cannot be located for AxisService
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Spring context file cannot be located for AxisService
    at org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.util.ApplicationContextUtil.getSpringApplicationContext(ApplicationContextUtil.java:120)
    at org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringAppContextAwareObjectSupplier.getServiceObject(SpringAppContextAwareObjectSupplier.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.makeNewServiceObject(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:176)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.getTheImplementationObject(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:224)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver.java:84)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:96)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.nationwide.cma.security.filter.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748
```

I have my context initialized  in web.xml like below

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-mycontex.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

also i have below entry in my `spring-mycontex.xml`

```
<bean id="Axis2ApplicationContext" class="org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.ApplicationContextHolder" />
```

Is there anyway to see what is causing this error?

Comment: Which version of Axis2 are you using, and I wouldn't expect that to be compatible anymore (at least YMMV). Is the `spring-mycontext.xml` really at the root of your classpath?

Comment: @M.Deinum, as part of migration i had to update the axi2-spring jar from 1.3 to 1.8. and yes, ```spring-mycontext.xml``` is in classpath and location is ```src/main/resources```

Comment: The `contextConfigLocation` is laoded by the `ContextLoaderListener` in Spring. Judging from the code of axis (had a quick glance) you now get a different error.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I see in axis2-spring 1.8 has different way to load the application context.. they are looking for ```axisService.getParameter("SpringApplicationContext")``` and in axis2-spring 1.3 uses ```ApplicationContext aCtx = ApplicationContextHolder.getContext();```
now i am getting ```SpringApplicationContext``` not found.. so does it mean i need to remove the application context file from web.xml and use axis to to load it?